# Rotation of images

Tags: python, windows, image, python-2.7, rotation

I need to rotate an image by 90, 180, and 270 degrees. I do not need to copy over the image, but rather save the rotated image as its own separate image. So far, my code will rotate the image but will not save it as its own separate file. This is what I have so far.

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
os.chdir("./")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    image = Image.open(file)
    image_rot_180 = image.rotate(180)
    image_rot_180.save(file.replace(".jpg", "_r180.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works (I tested it). Here's an improved version, that rotates each image by the 3 mentioned angles and saves it.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image


def main():
    img_dir = "./img"
    jpg_ext = ".jpg"
    angles = [90, 180, 270]
    for file_name in glob.iglob(os.path.join(img_dir, "*" + jpg_ext)):
        image = Image.open(file_name)
        for angle in angles:
            rot_suffix = "_r{:03d}{:s}".format(angle, jpg_ext)
            file_name_rot = file_name.replace(jpg_ext, rot_suffix)
            image_rot = image.rotate(angle)
            image_rot.save(file_name_rot)
            print("Rotated: {:s} by {:3d} degrees to {:s}".format(file_name, angle, file_name_rot))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056368107]> dir /b .\img
> image.jpg
> script_file.py
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056368107]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Rotated: ./img\image.jpg by  90 degrees to ./img\image_r090.jpg
> Rotated: ./img\image.jpg by 180 degrees to ./img\image_r180.jpg
> Rotated: ./img\image.jpg by 270 degrees to ./img\image_r270.jpg
>
> Done.
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056368107]> dir /b .\img
> image.jpg
> image_r090.jpg
> image_r180.jpg
> image_r270.jpg
> script_file.py
> ```

For more details regarding the operations performed on strings, check [[Python 3.Docs]: Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: The OP seeks to save under a different name, *not* to overwrite the original.

Answer (score 0):

Your exact code works perfectly as-is: given image `original.jpg`, it flips (rotates 180 degrees) and saves it as `original_r180.jpg`. The `os.chdir` is extraneous, since changing to the current directory is a null-op, but it's not wrong.

If you need to do all three, consider this:

```py
import glob
from PIL import Image
os.chdir("./")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    for angle in (90, 180, 270):
        image = Image.open(file)
        image_rot = image.rotate(angle)
        image_rot.save(file.replace(".jpg", "_r{0}.jpg".format(angle)))
```